# List is disappearing on refresh in react

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to map out a list to display file information on a grid. I think the issue lies with my keys. When I change the keys, it renders, but on refresh it disappears. I'm using a unique key for each list item.

```
const FileList = () => {
  const { state } = useDB();

  return (
    <div className='container'>
      <div className='fileList-wrapper'>
        <div className='fileList-wrapper__header'>Name</div>
        <div className='fileList-wrapper__header'>Last modified</div>
        <div className='fileList-wrapper__header'>File size</div>
        {state.childFolders.map((folder) => {
          return <ListItem key={folder.id} folder={folder} />;
        })}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Here is the child contents:

```
const ListItem = ({ folder }) => {
  return (
    <>
      <div
        id='fileName'
        className='fileList-wrapper__item'
        onDoubleClick={handleDoubleClick}>
        {folder.name}
      </div>
      <div className='fileList-wrapper__item'>{folder.timestamp}</div>
      <div className='fileList-wrapper__item'>{folder.fileSize}</div>
    </>
  );
};
```

Here is the function that sets my state:

```
const setChildFolders = () => {
    const childFolders = [];

    database.folders
      .where('parentId', '==', state.folderId)
      .where('userId', '==', currentUser.uid)
      .get()
      .then((snapshot) => {
        snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
          childFolders.push({ id: doc.id, ...doc.data() });
        });
      })
      .catch(() => {});

    setState((prev) => ({
      ...state,
      childFolders: childFolders,
    }));
  };
```

I'm calling that function in a useEffect:

```
useEffect(() => {
    setChildFolders();
  }, [currentFolder, currentUser]);
```

Just to reiterate, on first render, the list shows, but if I refresh, it disappears. If I then change the keys, it reappears.

Comment: Since your DB query is asynchronous, it's likely that `childFolders` isn't getting updated before it's being set to your state. Try moving the `setState()` call to inside the `then()` of the DB query, and see if that works.

Comment: That worked. Thank you so much!